# APK 0 (zero) Device compatibility

Tags: android, cordova

I'm generating an APK to publish on the store, it's an update of an exsisting app, after the upload on Google Play Console:

Supported Android devices: 0 devices

this is my manifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="104095" android:versionName="1.4.6" package="com.myapp.xyz" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
ext {
    apply from: 'cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

group = 'org.apache.cordova'
version = '6.2.3'

android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
    publishNonDefault true

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                name 'Cordova'
                url 'https://cordova.apache.org'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'stevengill'
                        name 'Steve Gill'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git'
                    developerConnection 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git'
                    url 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android'

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'cordova-android'
        userOrg = 'cordova'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git'
        websiteUrl = 'https://cordova.apache.org'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB'
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        labels = ['android', 'cordova', 'phonegap']
        version {
            name = '6.2.3'
            released  = new Date()
            vcsTag = '6.2.3'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your app build.gradle file 
It will be happen by any external library

Comment: I added build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in google play store you can upload the APK it will be visible for all the devices according to your configuration.

Comment: You win man :). After the rollout the console displays 'Supported Android devices 10778 devices '