# 0 Supported Device when uploaded to playstore

Tags: android, google-play, device

Please help me. I dont know why, when I trying to upload the apk from version code 21 to 22 and version Name from 305 to 306.. playstore showing me detail zero device supported. this is my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.android.studio"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="22"
android:versionName="3.0.6">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!---->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!---->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <!--
        The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
        (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
        Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
        You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
        sign the APK for publishing.
        You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity
        android:name=".Tutorial"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" />
</application>
```

this is my build.gradle (project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.studio"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true

    renderscriptTargetApi 25
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {

}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'// dif
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'// dif
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.adeel:easyFTP:1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my build.gradle (module:app)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}} allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in google play store you can upload the APK it will be visible for all the devices according to your configuration.

Refer my answer at

[APK 0 Device Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107159/apk-0-device-compatibility/44107818#44107818)

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer my question dude ! and now playstore show me 9621 device to me.

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer my question dude ! and now playstore show me 9621 device to me.